# Client-side events when calling a .asmx webservice via asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I'm trying to build a timeout capability for a ASP.NET website.  The idea is that after a certain amount of inactivity, the browser will be redirected to the login page.  (The code-behind for the login page clears authentication, so once you're there, you have to login to get anywhere else).

Now in old-style pages, with full postbacks, just setting a meta-refresh tag works.  Any action involves a postback, which means a new page, and a reset meta-refresh tag.

With UpdatePanels and partial postbacks, this doesn't work so well.  Doing a partial postback doesn't reload the page, so the meta-refresh never resets.  The user is redirected to login even if he's been very active on the page.  Not good.

The fix is to use javascript instead of meta-refresh.  A bit of code run by windows.setInterval() compares the current time against the time of last activity, and does the redirect when necessary.  Simple enough, but...

The critical bit is setting the last activity time.  For partial postbacks, this can be done by setting a handler on one or more of the Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager events.  I'm currently using initializeRequest, and it's working fine.  At the start of every partial postback, I reset the last activity variable, and all is good.  Except...

On some of my pages I also have code that's being executed via asynchronous calls to .asmx web services.  And these don't go through the Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager lifecycle, and initializeRequest is never called.

I could go into javascript around each of these calls, and add a bit that resets the last activity variable, but I'd rather not.  I'd rather have some clean hook that would be triggered by every call, as I do for partial postbacks.  But I haven't been able to find one - or, for that matter, any documentation into the .asmx webservice lifecycle.

Are there any client-side events raised during a call to a .asmx webservice?

Any pointers to where I can learn about them?

Answer (score 0):

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice.aspx. There is only one event, Disposed.

To your original question. You should not rely on Meta-refresh. Also, UpdatePanels do fire Page_Load and other events on server (not every event like when doing full postback though), so i do think you are not solving real problem when trying to use WebServices.

Comment: Meta-refresh does what it was designed to do just fine.  It just wasn't designed to do what I need to do.  As for Page_Load() - that's a server-side event.  It's got nothing to do with the javascript that is running on the browser.